# Handle special characters during textfile import into OracleDB via Apex

Tags: regex, blob, special-characters, oracle-apex, file-import

I'm working on a tool that imports textfiles into a BLOB column (OracleDB). This is handled via an Apex page with a File Browse button and connected import procedure.

For more details about the import to BLOB procedure: http://ittichaicham.com/2011/03/file-browser-in-apex-4-with-blob-column-specified-in-item-source-attribute/

The textfiles that I'm using contain special characters, null values, decimal seperators etc.  For example:

> (...) 111888|Overflakkée, Blabla|streetname with Rhône||12-13|UXC
>   Placename (...)

Since it's all character data, I'm converting the BLOB to CLOB with this procedure:

```
FUNCTION blob_to_clob (blob_in IN BLOB)
RETURN CLOB
AS
v_clob CLOB;
v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
v_start PLS_INTEGER := 1;
v_buffer PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
BEGIN
DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(v_clob, TRUE);

FOR i IN 1..CEIL(DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(blob_in) / v_buffer)
LOOP

   v_varchar := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(blob_in, v_buffer, v_start));

DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(v_clob, LENGTH(v_varchar), v_varchar);
v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
END LOOP;
RETURN v_clob;
END blob_to_clob;
```

See for more info:http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_convert_blob_to_clob_script.htm

The problem:
While converting the blob to clob, some of the special characters are lost/altered.

For example, this row:

> (...) 111888|Overflakkée, Blabla|streetname with Rhône||12-13|UXC
>   Placename (...)

will become this row:

> (...) 111888|Overflakk� Blabla|streetname with Rh�|12-13|UXC
>   Placename (...)

Row length, characters and even seperators (in this case a '|') are altered/not visible.

- Is there a way to obtain the lost characters + keep seperators/null values in place?      (if its necessary to change 'é' to 'e', that's fine).
- Is there a more efficient way to import textfiles into a BLOB/CLOB column?

Regards

Comment: To narrow down the problem, have you tried to import the file directly into your database (without using APEX) and see what result is? To me it looks more like language settings

Comment: Try to save the file with an UTF-8 encoding and after that upload the file. To do so open the file with Notepad>Save As> In the lower part of the window select UTF-8 as Encoding.

Comment: Indeed @Christian_l, importing the files with UTF-8 encoding is working. However, some characters are still lost: 'Privée' will become 'Prive', so special characters are removed. 

This could be the solution but there will be an extra requirement of delivering the files in UTF-8 format. This is workable.

- Does someone know of a way to automatically convert all incoming files to UTF-8 format, no matter what format they are originally in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a conversion from the source character set to the character set of the database

Here is an example I made (mainly for getting big json objects, javascript is utf8, to work with in a 8859p1 database), It's pretty simple so I won't explain it too much.

example usage with conversion:

```
l_clob := blob_to_clob (l_blob, '1');
```

Function:

```
function blob_to_clob (blob_in in blob, p_convertutf8 in char default 0)
   return clob as
   /* Ólafur Tryggvason */
   l_clob           clob;
   l_varchar        varchar2 (32767);
   l_start          pls_integer := 1;
   l_buffer         pls_integer := 32767;
   l_characterset   nls_database_parameters.value%type;
begin
   select value
     into l_characterset
     from nls_database_parameters
    where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

   dbms_lob.createtemporary (l_clob, true);

   for i in 1 .. ceil (dbms_lob.getlength (blob_in) / l_buffer) loop
      l_varchar := utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 (dbms_lob.substr (blob_in, l_buffer, l_start));

      if p_convertutf8 = '1' then
         l_varchar := convert (l_varchar, l_characterset, 'UTF8'); -- WE8ISO8859P1
      end if;

      dbms_lob.writeappend (l_clob, length (l_varchar), l_varchar);

      l_start := l_start + l_buffer;
   end loop;

   return l_clob;
end blob_to_clob;
```